# Calling a parameterized function from a procedure where the function name is stored in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am having n number of functions. Consider n=10

I have stored the names of these n functions in an array named Array1

Example: Array1= Array("Function_1",Function_2","Function_3"............,"Function_10")

General Structure of these functions:

Function Function_1(TestRange as Range) as Range

...Some code

End Function

When I call this function using the array index how do I pass the parameter for TestRange?

Eg:

Sub main()

Dim MainRange as Range

```
For i = 1 To UBound(Array1)
    Set MainRange = Application.Run(Array1(i))
Next
```

End Sub

When I try to run main() procedure I am encountering the following error:

Run-Time Error '449' : Argument Not Optional

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks,

Akshat

Comment: Pass it as the second argument to Run.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim arr, x
    Dim rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range

    arr = Array("Func1", "Func2")
    Set rngIn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Set rngOut = Application.Run(arr(x), rngIn)
        Debug.Print rngOut.Address()
    Next x

End Sub

Function Func1(rng As Range) As Range
    Set Func1 = rng.Resize(10, 1)
End Function

Function Func2(rng As Range) As Range
    Set Func2 = rng.Resize(1, 10)
End Function
```